# open new window from xib in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

My first project is a tool which changes the wallpaper according to the time of the day.

Therefore, I want to create a little window to select the wallpapers.

I have an alertView with three Buttons (kill changer/cancel/set wallpapers).
Pressing "set wallpapers" will run the method wall setter:

```
//method to set / copy / rename the wallpapers
- (void)wallsetter {

//copy chosen wallpaper to specified folder and rename it according to the time

printf("wallsetter starts...\n");

NSWindowController * wc=[[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"setter"];

[wc showWindow:self];

}
```

I also created a window called setter.xib with the Interface I like it to have which is now located in "supporting files".

By pressing "set wallpapers" that window should show up, but it does not. Can someone tell me how to do it? All I find are examples with .nib files but they have been replaced with the .xib.

if it helps here is a link to the complete code: [wallchange@pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zbBX1PM5)

Comment: your `NSWindowController` is released in the scope. so `wc` needs to be an instance variable.

Comment: so it is the correct way to use a window even if the method is 'initWithWindowNibName' and using a .xib file?  wc is a variable i thought? i am really new to objective C, please excuse that .   shouldn't it be the same like: [[[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"setter"] showWindow:self]? with this implementation i still get now window shown.

Comment: your initialization code of `NSWindowController` is perfectly correct. the problem is that `wc` is a local variable, i think. add `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSWindowController *wc;` like other properties, and store the reference which you created in wallsetter method to the property.

Comment: thanks a lot! works fine with that changes